# Elasticsearch Geodistance calculation using a "distance field" local to the document

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to query using a "radius" stored within the document?

For example, I provide a geopoint and I want to return all documents where the radius plus it's own geopoint contain the provided geopoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store your location and radius (named `area` below) as a [`geo_shape` circle type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html#_circle) and then using a [`geo_shape` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html) search for documents whose `area` contains the given point.

```
# 1. create the index with the geo_shape field
PUT index
{
    "mappings": {
        "type": {
            "properties": {
                "area": { "type": "geo_shape" }
            }
        }
    }
}

# 2. index a document with a shape
PUT index/type/1
{
  "area" : {
    "type" : "circle",
    "coordinates" : [-45.0, 45.0],
    "radius" : "100m"
  }
}

# 3. use a geo_shape query

POST index/type/_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool": {
        "filter": {
            "geo_shape": {
                "area": {
                    "shape": {
                        "type": "point",
                        "coordinates" : [-45.0001, 45.0001]
                    },
                    "relation": "contains"
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response! Yes, this is how I accomplished it, thanks!